# How to change the font and background color for Blog Terminal in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I was using blog terminal plugins in WordPress for my website. but the color is not suitable. Please check the below screenshot. How to change this color?

[image]

I am using below statement after the plugin installation.

[terminal]ls -lrt [/terminal]

Please help me on that.

Comment: What plugin is this?

Comment: plugin name is "Blog Terminal"

Comment: you'll have to post a link to your page with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the statement, just install the plugin and give style to your element in the style.css like you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using [Blog Terminal](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-terminal/) the plugin and its output is as you shared the screenshot then it must be a css conflict
2. Add following css in you active themes style.css

   `.terminal code {
   background-color: #000 !important;
   color: #ffffff !important;
   }`